# Trying to access items from an API gives errors

Tags: python, json, flask

So I am trying to return a float value from an API, it is located in:
products => product_name => sell/buy_summary => pricePerUnit

and can be found in this API:
https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/bazaar?key=73ac0a44-4c41-4933-a9ee-b4095be2b6d2

When I am returning it to my HTML I get the error "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str", I've googled around a bit and also saw the other thread here on Stackoverflow but didn't get it to work. I have another way to grab values that works completely fine, but the issue is that I NEED to save these values into a variable, to run a script through it to calculate profit/margins.

Here is my current code:

```
@app.route('/bflipper', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def bFlipper():
    f = requests.get(
        'https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/bazaar?key=73ac0a44-4c41-4933-a9ee-b4095be2b6d2').json()
    product_name = []
    product_sellPrice = []
    product_buyPrice = []
    for x in productNames:
        product_name.append(f["products"][x]["product_id"])
        product_buyPrice.append(
            f["products"][x]["buy_summary"]["pricePerUnit"])
        product_sellPrice.append(
            f["products"][x]["sell_summary"]["pricePerUnit"])
    if request.method == 'POST':
        userInput = request.form['coins']
        return render_template("flipper.html", userInput=userInput, product_name=product_name, product_buyPrice=product_buyPrice, product_sellPrice=product_sellPrice)
    else:
        return render_template("flipper.html", product_name=product_name, product_buyPrice=product_buyPrice, product_sellPrice=product_sellPrice)
```

This script works for arrays though, so I need to get all "pricePerUnit"s from the API, every single product (190+) and store that in the array, this is the reason why I would like to be able to store the "pricePerUnit" first in variables (sellPrice & buyPrice), and then append that to two different arrays so I can run my script through it!

OBS: I am going to need the 'pricePerUnit' for both 'sell_summary' and 'buy_summary' from each product!

Thanks

Comment: `sell_summary` and `buy_summary` are arrays. So there are multiple prices, what do you want to do with them?

Comment: Which `pricePerUnit` do you want to append to `product_sellPrice` and `product_buyPrice`?

Comment: @Barmar both "sell_summary" & "buy_summary" (inside of the API), consists of a "pricePerUnit", which is the price of both selling and buying the product. I need to save the price of "sell_summary" & "buy_summary" inside of a variable, which I later can use for a script.

Comment: Did you look at the JSON? It consists of an array like `[{"amount":20181,"pricePerUnit":4.1,"orders":1},{"amount":28630,"pricePerUnit":4.0,"orders":1},{"amount":35037,"pricePerUnit":3.9,"orders":1},{"amount":140326,"pricePerUnit":3.8,"orders":2}]`

Comment: There are 4 different `pricePerUnit` for different amounts. Which of them do you want in your variable?

Comment: The top "pricePerUnit" is the latest updated pricePerUnit, and that's what I am interested in. @Barmar

Comment: The top 'sections' for both "sell_summary" & "buy_summary" is the latest updated, its from a market that constantly updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `buySummary` and `sellSummary` are arrays, you need to use an array index to get the price from the first element.

```
for x in productNames:
    if x in f["products"]:
        product_name.append(f["products"][x]["product_id"])
        if len(f["products"][x]["buy_summary"]) > 0:
            product_buyPrice.append(
                f["products"][x]["buy_summary"][0]["pricePerUnit"])
        if len(f["products"][x]["sell_summary"]) > 0:
            product_sellPrice.append(
                f["products"][x]["sell_summary"][0]["pricePerUnit"])
```

Comment: I have tried doing this: https://pastebin.com/d722cTqs | But I get the error: IndexError: list index out of range on "f["products"][x]["buy_summary"][0]["pricePerUnit"])", I got that issue before as well, when I tried having "[0]" in between buy/sell_summary and "pricePerUnit"

Comment: Maybe some of them have empty arrays, you need to check for that.

Comment: I've added checking that the product name is in the list, and that it has at least one price.

Comment: I got it to work! Forgot to 'check answer', my bad! But thank you.